# C Function Pointers - What happens when you drop an argument?

Tags: c, function, pointers, signature, arguments

all.  I'm currently working with an old established code base for a new project which is basically undocumented (i.e. averages 1 one-line comment per file).  I just ran into something which I haven't seen before and am not quite sure how to interpret.

Firstly, they define a function type and a function in the header file (.h) in the form:

```
typedef void (*SOME_FUNCTION)(void *data, EXECUTION_CONTEXT *ec);
void add_function(SOME_FUNCTION aFunction, void *data);
```

In the main source file (.c), there is a function defined:

```
void add_function(void (*f)(void *data), void *data) 
{
   (Some code here)
}
```

So okay, there's a function pointer... but what the heck happened to the second argument, ec?  Why would someone use a code design like this?  For reference, when the function add_function is used, it is used in this sort of form:

```
void passedFunction(void *data, EXECUTION_CONTEXT *ec) 
{
    (Stuff the function does.)
}

void CallingFunction()
{
    data = (some data stuff);
    add_function((SOME_FUNCTION)passedFunction, data);
}
```

So, as you can see, the passed functions use the correct form that fits the original SOME_FUNCTION argument signature, but the definition for the add_function arguments is short by one argument.

Comment: I assume void function(....) is the add_function() that you are speaking of?  Also, function pointers are generally accepted in the C world; as such it's not that strange to see them.

Comment: Whoops, yes, that was a typo.  I replaced the specific function names and didn't substitute properly right there.  Corrected that.  It's not the function pointer I find odd though- it's that its argument signature differs when describing the pointer, as compared to the actual typedef or functions being passed in.  I don't know why this is done, or if I should consider that to be in error.  The original coder is long gone, so it's not like I can ask.

Comment: And so should I consider this to be an error in code probably?  By my money, I would assume that the implemented function definition should be:

Comment: As I stated in my answer; it doesn't appear that the arguments listed during the prototype actually matter for the pointer itself.  But I think for your benefit you should change the function definition to match the function prototype.

Comment: Sorry, timed out on the edit, I think it should be: add_function(void (*f)(void *data, EXECUTION_CONTEXT *ec), void *data)  rather than add_function(void (*f)(void *data), void *data).  From my looking of how this is used in practice, the "ec" parameter is being passed to the functions when they're actually called (i.e. during the 'some code here' phase).

Comment: Okay, cool.  That is basically what I'm doing right now.  I need to do some pretty substantial changes to parts of the code base, and since there is A. No documentation and B. No unit tests I need to improve the form and add documentation as much as possible to reflect what is supposed to be going on.  Thanks so much for the help on this.

Comment: Yah, the state of the code base is... problematic, to say the least.  If I was on this code base for the long haul, my first month would be entirely devoted to adding tests to the existing stuff.  Instead, it's one week to figure out what is going on- 3 weeks to implement new features.  C'est la vie.

Comment: Also, everybody's answers were good- but I voted for Root's because he took the time to play with the problem on a relevant compiler, helping to frame later discussion (which was also quite useful, by the way).  Thanks to everyone for the assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the example code below, it doesn't appear that the variable(s) that are defined in the function pointer matters during the check.  The code below compiles without warning.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int temp(int (*m)());

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
        return temp(main);
}

int temp(int (*m)()) {
        return 1;
}
```

However, the code below throws an error.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int temp(void (*m)());

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
        return temp(main);
}

int temp(void (*m)()) {
        return 1;
}
```

Due to this; it seems that the compiler (at least in my case GCC) only cares what the return value of the function pointer will be.  The interesting thing here is that you CAN send the parameters correctly but if you do NOT specify the parameter (in our example m()), then the variables in m() when called will be junk.

Comment: +1 For going to the effort of testing something with a real (and commonly used) implementation.

Comment: @Conrad: Not sure if that is sarcasm; I realize that passing the main function to another function is not exactly something that would occur in the real world.  Was just a general example.  If you were to actually call m() from temp, you would end up in an infinite recursion loop.

Comment: No, not sarcasm. I was referring to the C implementation -- GCC.

Comment: This is hardly a reasonable test, since no call is ever made through the function pointer.  Furthermore, you're defining the function pointer without specifying the argument list (unspecified arguments are quite different from an empty argument list), try `int temp(int (*m)(void))` instead and you'll get an error.

Answer (score 3):

Formally, the results are undefined:  you are only permitted to call a function via a function pointer if the types match.

As for what actually happens, it depends on the calling convention and what the function does with the arguments.  Chances are, the results aren't going to be good.

Comment: And ideally, what happens next is that the person who wrote the code gets retrained or fired.  Casting function pointers is always a bad idea, with the singular exception of `GetProcAddress`/`dlopen`.

Comment: @Ben:  And overload disambiguation, though the intent in that case is very different.

Comment: @James: I wouldn't use a cast in that case, initialization of a local is much more type-safe.

Comment: @Ben:  Well, with a `static_cast` no type safety is lost (since you can't generally `static_cast` function pointers, you're guaranteed that the type matches the type of one of the overloads).  Of course, you're right:  the `static_cast` is quite different from the fugly/horrible C cast.

Comment: @James: Probably so, but I try to never use a cast for a conversion available implicitly.  If the infix behavior of the cast is preferred over a local variable, define `inline T implicit_cast<T>(const T& t) { return t; }` and have the type-safety of implicit conversion with the style of a cast.  But that would be for C++, this question is about C.

Comment: @Ben: Alas, the original programmer is long gone- this code base hasn't seen changes to its core for quite some time (2003ish).  Which also explains (though only partially) why code that should have been written in C++ is all in C.  I can only hope his next employer was a nut about docstrings, because no one else should ever have to deal with undocumented code that uses a variable called "memory_free" as a counter of how many blocks of memory are ALLOCATED.  ("Hmm... why is one more thing free after we just added another item to the structure...?")

Answer (score 3):

To add on James' answer:

Since the default calling convention is most likely [`cdecl`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#cdecl), the call site is responsible for cleaning up the stack after `passedFunction` returns. Since the call site knows that it passed just 1 argument to the callee, the compiler can clean up the stack normally (even though technically this is undefined behavior).

Change the calling convention on `passedFunction` to [`stdcall`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#stdcall) though, and you 're in for some fireworks.

Comment: James's isn't right, it should be James'. You pronounce James's though.

Comment: @nightcracker:  I disagree:  If "James's" is good enough for "[St. James's Park](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St._James's_Park)" it's good enough for me.

Comment: @nightcracker, @James: Nightcracker wins by unanimous decision of the SE jury: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1073/what-is-the-correct-possessive-for-nouns-ending-in-s. Seems that proper names don't get an s after the apos.

Comment: Though after reading a bit, according to Wikipedia both are correct and used.

Comment: @James: Read even further: "There is a partial exception for proper names that end in -s".

Comment: Shhhh.  Stop reading!  [It does, however, say "sometimes"  :-)]